# JavaFX 8 (Release Candidate) Transparency issue

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application using a full transparent window.
Code:

```
...
scene.setFill(null);
...
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
...
```

That worked without a problem, until I installed the release candidate of `Java 8`. Now I am not able to get it to behave like before *(display the background transparent as expected)*.

I have been googling for days, but everywhere it is always stated that this should work. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Christian

Comment: Solved it: #AnchorPane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent; was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#my-root-component { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
```

In application css solved it for me as well. Thanks!